# I'm having an error that says NoReverseMatch at /app1/add_post/

Tags: python, django, url, frame, reverse

Every time I try to update or create a post in the blog I'm creating, this error always pops up, it saves the information, but it doesn't redirect the page to the url I'm sending it to. Here's the code so you guys can check it out.

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
from datetime import datetime, date
# Create your models here.


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length= 255)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name 
    

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    post_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255, default = 'coding')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + ' | ' + str(self.author)
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('app1:article-detail', args =(str(self.id)))
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.urls import reverse, reverse_lazy
from .forms import  PostForm, PostUpdateForm
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from .models import Post, Category



# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'app1/index.html')

class PostView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'app1/post.html'
    ordering = ['post_date']

class ArticleDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'app1/article_details.html'

class AddPostView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'app1/createpost.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('app1:article-detail')
    #fields = '__all__'

class UpdatePostView(UpdateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostUpdateForm
    template_name = 'app1/update_post.html'

class DeletePostView(DeleteView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'app1/delete_post.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

class AddCategoryView(CreateView):
    model = Category
    template_name = 'app1/add_category.html'
    fields = '__all__'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('app1:Post')
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from app1 import views
from .views import PostView, ArticleDetailView, AddPostView, UpdatePostView, DeletePostView, AddCategoryView

app_name = 'app1'

urlpatterns = [
    path('post/', PostView.as_view(), name = 'Post'),
    path('article/<int:pk>', ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name = 'article-detail'),
    path('add_post/',AddPostView.as_view(), name='addpost'),
    path('update_post/<int:pk>', UpdatePostView.as_view(), name = 'updatepost'),
    path('delete_post/<int:pk>', DeletePostView.as_view(), name = 'deletepost'),
    path('add_category/', AddCategoryView.as_view(), name = 'add_category')
]
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from app1 import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name = "index"),
    path('app1/', include('app1.urls')),
    path('members/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('members/', include('members.urls'))
]
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Post, Category

#choices = [('coding', 'coding'), ('sports', 'sports'), ('entertainment', 'entertainment')]
choices = Category.objects.all().values_list('name', 'name')

choice_list = []

for item in choices:
    choice_list.append(item)


class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'author','category', 'body')

        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Title', 'length':'100px'}),
            'author': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'category': forms.Select(choices = choice_list,attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Choices'}),
            'body': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
        }

class PostUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'body')

        widgets = {
        'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Title'}),
        'body': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
        }
```

Error:

NoReverseMatch at /app1/add_post/
Reverse for 'article-detail' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['app1/article/(?P[0-9]+)$']
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/app1/add_post/
Django Version: 3.0.3
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:
Reverse for 'article-detail' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['app1/article/(?P[0-9]+)$']
Exception Location: C:\Users\snin2\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 677
Python Executable:  C:\Users\snin2\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.3
Python Path:
['C:\Users\snin2\Desktop\basura\lapagina',
'C:\Users\snin2\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\python38.zip',
'C:\Users\snin2\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\DLLs',
'C:\Users\snin2\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib',
'C:\Users\snin2\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv',
'C:\Users\snin2\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 3 Aug 2020 20:53:37 +0000

I'm not sure why I'm receiving this error since Im using the reverse feature.

Comment: Show us the full error traceback and the patterns tried from the debug page.

Comment: I edited it so you can see the error

Comment: Your `reverse_lazy()` is missing the `pk` argument.

Comment: How should I put it?

Comment: And in which of the reverse lazy?

Comment: Instead of sharing your `models.py` and `forms.py` files make sure to add `app1/createpost.html`. Because the problems aren't in these files

Comment: One more thing I notice is that you are using `app_name='app1' ` in `app1/urls.py` but not including this namespace in `urls.py` file. Try to add `include('app1.urls', namespace='app1')` . And to link this app's url with template use this syntax `{% url 'app1:your_url_name' %}'`